# Program an lcd display with 12 pins

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, lcd, display

I have a screen just like [this](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1111342/Topway/LM32019T/1) (is the datasheet). My question is,

Can I use it to an Arduino board?

Comment: you probably can use it ... it is unknown what the user experience will be like ... you have not included a link to the actual datasheet

Comment: Can you tell me how, I don't know if exists any library for this type of screen. This is the only datasheet that I found. I tried to find more information's about it  and zero success.

Comment: first, you have to find a datasheet for the LCD control IC that is used in that display

Comment: Can be this ones ? https://imgur.com/a/e5DD9U4

Comment: The datasheet is [here](https://www.topwaydisplay.com/sites/default/files/2020-02/LM32019TFW.pdf), it provided sufficient info to experiencing with. But it probably not worth the effort to write the library.